# Simple way to disable model validation for disabled form input?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there a simple way to disable model validation on disabled input fields? My issue is I have a form with model validation I'm using jquery to disable an input and hide it and using Ajax to submit the form but it still does model validation on that field when it's disabled I'm using html 5 validation for client side and model validation for server side. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is only part of my code its much bigger but I just wanted to know if there was a simple way to disable model validation on a disabled input field. Not sure if you will be able to tell how it works with my code examples I tried to simplify them to get the point across but I think I might have slaughtered it. I remove the required html 5 and disabled from the location text box to test for the model validation which works great but I don't want it to work when the location text box is disabled.

## Part of Model

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a location")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage ="Must Be Under 15 Characters")]
    public string location_txt_box { get; set; }
```

## Part of Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAjax]
    public JsonResult AddData(form_model form_data)
    {
        return Json(form_data);
    }

    public class ValidateAjaxAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return;

            var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
            if (!modelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errorModel =
                        from x in modelState.Keys
                        where modelState[x].Errors.Count > 0 select new
                        {
                            key = x,
                            errors = modelState[x].Errors.Select(y => y.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                        };
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = errorModel
                };
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            }
        }
    }
```

## Part of View

```
<section class="u_select_section">
                    <center>
                        <label>
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.user_department_radio_group,"user", htmlAttributes: new{
                            @id = "u_select"
                            })
                            Filling out for myself
                        </label>

                    </center>
                </section>

                <section id="location_display_section" class="location_display_section">

                   <div id="location_error"></div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.location_txt_box, htmlAttributes: new{

                   @id = "dep_loca_id",
                   @disabled = "disabled",
                   @placeholder = "Type your Location",
                   @required = "required" 
               })

                </section>
```

## Part of jquery

```
$('#request_form').on('submit', function (e) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Home/AddData",
                datatype: "json",
                data: $("#request_form").serializeArray(),

                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#progress").show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#progress').hide("fade",2000);
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    alert("Success")

                },
                error: function (data) {

                    $("#location_error").show();
                    var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                    var location_error = response[0].errors[0];
                    $("#location_error").text("" + location_error + "").css({ "color": "red" });

                }

            });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

## Jquery for hide and disable

```
//disable functions
    function disable_function_1(i) {
        return $(i).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }  

    //user and department radio button click functions
    $("#u_select").click(function () {


       $(dep_loca_id).hide(effect1);//hide the department location text box
        disable_function_1(dep_loca_id);//disable the department location text box

    });
```

Comment: post some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove specific field validation with `ModelState.Remove()`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(YourModel model)  
{
    // your condition here
    ModelState.Remove("location_txt_box "); // to omit specific field according to condition

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      // your code here
    }   

    return View();
}
```

Comment: That may work just have to figure out if text box is disabled for the condition just not to sure if I can check for that still kinda new to mvc and c# I'll give it a try

Comment: when do you disable your text box input?

Comment: are able to  understand whether your user and department radio buttons cliked by using your model?

Comment: In my model I have them set up as strings for the radio buttons I had them as bools at first but I wasn't getting what I wanted from them. I get the value when I put a break point to see what is going to the model its user or department depends on which one is selected I disable the text box when the user selects the user radio button

Comment: so you can add condition by checking your model before ModelState.Remove()

Comment: Yea I'll give it a try in a bit see what I can figure out ill let you know what I figure out thanks for your help so far

Comment: I'll try it sometime tonight doing some stuff for farthers day.

Comment: I put the modelState.Remove in my validate Ajax above and it works just having an issue accessing the form post data I can't get the value from the radio button in the validate Ajax to make my condition I can get an ICollection of the post values but can't get the value out of out of the ICollection

Comment: You can also send Your radio button values via ajax so you can use them in Conttoller to condition

Comment: I thought I was sending all the form values to the server in the Ajax data I can see them when I put breakpoints in just not for sure how to get the value I'll have to test some more see what I can figure out I'll have to update my code to explain what I'm doing you have been great help thanks